# sound mute-ing on every thing I try

Tags: sound

The sound on this machine worked pretty well until a few days ago (okay, so sound is not the very most important thing to me, but, the lack of it is getting old).

When I click the speaker icon it always says "**Mute**", when I set it to "**Unmute**" the slider goes to zero. When I move the *slider off of zero*, the status goes to "**Mute**".
So, does anyone know what's going on with my system?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the speaker icon, it shows you the action and not status. So pressing **Mute** will *mute* your audio while **Unmute** will do the opposite.

Status is shown by icon itself. So if your icon is something like [image: mute], then it means that your sound is *muted* and then you must see an **Unmute** option.

Comment: Well, in any case: I got no sound and all diagnostic report no problems...